# Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() not returning available cores

Tags: multithreading, jvm, cpu-cores

We have a highend server machine with 4 Intel Xeon E7 4850 processors (NUMA nodes) each having 10 cores with 2 threads. So effectively we have 80 core a machine.
(windows task manager shows 80 cores)
Now my question is when I execute
`Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`
it returns 40 and so my application spawns only 40 threads.
Why is it so?

Comment: Might be good idea to have an option to override the automatic thread allocation your app is doing by configuration, sidestepping the issue of the JVM being able to figure it out correctly.

Comment: file a bug at http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/

Comment: i cannot override as on a machine with 8 core it is returning 8 and thus 8 threads are spawned. I don't before hand where my application will run. It should run on a normal server machine as well as a high end machine like i have mentioned in my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using Windows 2003 which had a bug: *"The number of physical hyperthreading-enabled processors or the number of physical multicore processors is incorrectly reported in Windows Server 2003"*...

...a count of "40 Cores" is the wrong result if Hyper-Threading is enabled, which seems to be the case since Windows reports the correct number of logical CPU Cores.

If a Java fix is not available then you can use JNI to [call the GetLogicalProcessorInformation() Windows API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194.aspx) (source code included, works on XP SP3 and more recent).